# How are thumbnails stored on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, thumbnails, file-location

I have noticed that thumbnails on Mac OS X don't seem to be generated every time I open a folder, but to be somehow "cached" instead.

I wasn't able, however, to find a folder where they clearly look to be stored.

I thought then they could be saved as some kind of metadata; i found, however, that when deleting a file (e.g. from the Desktop) and saving immediately after a file by the same name, the preview for the previous file is showed for ~ a second.

Are they stored separately from data? How and when are they invalidated (e.g. only when a file by the same name appears in the same directory)?

Comment: Probably in the infamous `.DS_Store` file in the same directory.

Comment: I also took this as a possibility, however it [doesn't seem to contain](https://wiki.mozilla.org/DS_Store_File_Format) anything about the thumbnails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `quicklookd` background process is responsible for creating and managing file thumbnails. Those thumbnails are stored in a folder named `com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache` in a folder like `/var/folders/39/ggldtdps6034ct7d_y6x4_v80000gn/C` that is specific to your user account. The file `index.sqlite` contains a SQLite database with information about stored thumbnails; access it using the `sqlite3` command line tool.

Comment: Great! I was able to dump the `index.sqlite` db, take a look and get an insight of how this works! Thanks :)

Comment: On macOS Big Sur, `find /var -name com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache` returns nothing. Maybe the path has changed?